# Cómo hacer una martingala realista

Tags: r

Aquí adjudico una fórmula para intentar replicar el método de la martingala (apostar una cantidad específica de dinero e ir doblando la apuesta si fallamos en un intento de recuperar la pérdida; por ejemplo, si se tienen 1000 euros y se apuestan 200, de acertar, tendremos 1200 euros; de perder y quedar en 800 euros, doblaremos la apuesta a 400, resultando en 1200 euros y seguir apostando de 200 en 200; de fallar y quedar en 400, tendríamos que doblar la apuesta una vez más (esta vez a 800) para recuperar las pérdidas, y por el impedimento de no poder apostar dinero que no se tiene, el proceso termina, al igual que si nos quedáramos sin dinero).

Esta es la sintaxis usada.

```
Nueva_Martingala <- function(b,a,n,p){
  for(i in 1:n){
    dinero <- b
    cantidad_apostada <- a
    end_Sim <- FALSE
    while(!end_Sim){
      color <- runif(1,0,1)
      if(color < p){
        dinero <- dinero + cantidad_apostada
        cantidad_apostada <- a
        } else {
        dinero <- dinero - cantidad_apostada
        cantidad_apostada <- a*2
     } if(dinero < cantidad_apostada|i==500)
        end_Sim <- TRUE
  }
 } return(dinero)
}
```

Y al intentar ejecutarla, me salen los consiguientes errores:

```
Error: unexpected 'if' in:
"        cantidad_apostada <- a*2
     } if"
>         end_Sim <- TRUE
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>  } return(dinero)
Error: unexpected '}' in " }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

¿Hay algo que esté pasando por alto? ¿Existe un bucle distinto que me permita hacer mejor la tarea en cuestión? Mi gratitud por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una buena práctica cuando se escriben bucles o varios condicionales dentro de una función o programa, dejar un espacio entre los bloques de cada sentencia.

Esto no sólo permitirá identificar si involuntariamente hemos olvidado colocar un corchete `}` también hará el código más legible y por ende facilitar su revisión.

Adicionalmente me gustaría agregar que al efectuarse simulaciones es útil ver el comportamiento que siguen nuestras variables aleatorias ([estocásticas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceso_estoc%C3%A1stico)) mediante una gráfica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes intentar el código aquí en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/StarchyRubberyCompiler)

## Sobre el código

En la linea `return(dinero)` sólo se devuelve el dinero que nos queda en la última ronda de apuestas, es decir la última iteración del bucle `for` cuando `i<-n` (en este caso 4)

Lo anterior quiere decir que **¿el bucle `for` no se necesita?** en mi opinión sí en la mayoría de casos, lo que se busca frecuentemente es realizar al menos 30 `n=30` réplicas a través de un bucle `for`, para luego aplicar el [TLC](https://rpubs.com/phobos/TLC) con los datos que arroje el modelo Martingala y establecer un intervalo de confianza para saber cuánto dinero en promedio va quedando a través de las apuestas efectuadas en una ronda, con un nivel de confianza del 95% si se apuesta con una moneda no trucada: `p = 0.5` (no es p-value).

Hay que tener presente que los datos a emplearse en la construcción del Intervalo de Confianza provienen del dinero promedio obtenido de las apuestas en cada una de las `n` rondas.

Por tanto, antes de quebrar el bucle `while` se debería capturar los datos antes señalados en cada iteración del bucle `for`, para ello se definen previamente `dineroFinal <- c()`, `dineroPromedio  <- c()` fuera del bucle `for` y dentro del bucle `while`:

```
if(dinero < cantidad_apostada|i==500){
               dineroFinal <- c(dineroFinal, dinero)
               dineroPromedio <- c(dineroPromedio, mean(camino))
               end_Sim <- TRUE
            }
```

Para terminar como las funciones en R no devuelve dos variables (objetos) separadas, se crea un lista

```
return(list(dineroFinal, dineroPromedio))
```

Luego se puede emplear esta función para construir el IC

```
a <- Nueva_Martingala(n=100, g=F) #100 réplicas y desactivamos las gráficas    
t.test(unlist(a[2]), conf.level = 0.95)
```

Actualicé el código que compartí en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/StarchyRubberyCompiler) teniendo esta última consideración.

Comment: Agregué el Intervalo de Confianza - IC

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que el problema es la forma en que se evalúan las sentencias en R, básicamente no se pueden evaluar dos sentencias que compartan el espacio en una misma línea (a menos que indiquemos el fin de la primera).

por ejemplo:

```
> if (1==1) {} {x<-'Hola'}print(x)
Error: inesperado '{' in "if (1==1) {} {"
```

Sin embargo, si agregamos un indicador de fin de la primer sentencia, es decir `;`

```
> if (1==1) {x<-'Hola'};print(x)
[1] "Hola"
```

Hay que entender que `if`, `while` y `for` son sentencias que contemplan las llaves por lo que cuando haces: `} if(dinero < cantidad_apostada|i==500)` o `} return(dinero)` estas combinando parte de una sentencia con la siguiente. Podrías hacerlo, agregando `;`, es decir `};if(dinero < cantidad_apostada|i==500)` o `}; return(dinero)`. O bien, me parece mejor criterio, agregar un salto de línea despues de cada llave de cierre.

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho quisiera agregar que los corchetes se pueden obviar si van en una línea `if (1==1) x<-'Hola'; print(x)` o `for (i in 1:10) print(i*i)`